# mouse scroll events work only in the space available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mousewheel

i am creating a flipping book using turn.js and jquery . i want to flip pages when mouse is scroll up or down . it works perfectly good . but problem is that it only scrolls single or double, in the browser space available on page.

here is my the link.

http://sajidshah.com/proof/flippingbook/index.php?direction=rtl#page/4

and the code is.

```
$(function(){
          //Keep track of last scroll
          var lastScroll = 0;
          $(window).scroll(function(event){
              //Sets the current scroll position
              var st = $(this).scrollTop();
              //Determines up-or-down scrolling
              if (st > lastScroll){
                next();
                event.preventDefault();
              }
              else {
                 previous();
                 event.preventDefault();
              }
              //Updates scroll position
              lastScroll = st;
           });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

use following code.....

```
window.onload = function()
{
    //adding the event listerner for Mozilla
if(window.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', moveObject, false);

//for IE/OPERA etc
document.onmousewheel = moveObject;
}
function moveObject(event)
{

if (!event) event = window.event;

 if (event.wheelDelta) {


} else if (event.detail) {

   }

}
```

Comment: The owner is using jQuery. In that case it goes: `$(window).on("mousewheel", ...)` with `evt.originalEvent.deltaX|Y|Z`